# running Apache on a different port

Tags: windows-7, services

I have installed Apache 2.2, but I can't run it because port 80 is used by TCP. What can I do? Could I change the port for TCP or assign another port to apache?

What I think is that I could stop TCP services, but it may harm my computer, network connection and so on. Another solution might be to give an available port to TCP and leave 80 for apache, but how to do it?

I have done a lot of research on the internet, but could not find any helpful tutorial. I don't have strong IT-experience and couldn't find out for myself.

Comment: instead of guessing aroung a lot yourself, you could post the actual error message.

Comment: i have installed XAMP,when i click  apache,it writes apache services started,but actually it is not started

Comment: This question makes no sense.  All http connections are tcp connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the sysinternals [TCPView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx), open it and see which service is running on local port 80. ( instead of 80 there will probably stand http(d)  ). Then shut down that service (if you aren't using it).

If you realy want to run apache on a different port: go to your apache config file (usually: C:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf) open it with notepad and change "Listen 80" to "Listen 81". Save it, restart apache and your apache is now running on port 81. To verify go to your browser and browse to localhost:81 .

NOTE: Change your topic title to "running apache on a different port" because this isn't a bug.